# Erro ao gerar gráfico de barras: 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Tags: r

Olá! Ao construir um gráfico de barras em `R Language` usando o `RStudio` me deparei com o seguinte erro:

```
Error in barplot.default(database$results, main = "EvasionChart", xlab = rotulo[1],  : 
'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Pesquisei um pouco sobre, vi respostas de vários tipos mas que não resolveram meu problema, para auxiliar no contexto estou compartilhando o script. Segue Abaixo o código:

```
database <- data.frame("curso" = 1:10, "e_eolica" = 1:10)
database$curso <- c("ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemC", "ItemD", "ItemE", "ItemF", "ItemG", "ItemH", "ItemI", "sdois")
database$results <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
rotulo <-  c(1, 2)

par(mgp=c(1,1,0))
png(filename = "C:/Users/BREWERTONTHIAGOOLIVE/Desktop/chart.png", width = 800, height = 800)
barplot(database$results, main = "EvasionChart", xlab = rotulo[1], ylab = rotulo[2], names.arg = database$curso, ylim = c(0, database$results[8]), cex.names = 0.8, xaxs = "i")
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL)
barplot(database$results, main = "EvasionChart", xlab = rotulo[1], ylab = rotulo[2], names.arg = database$curso, ylim = c(0, database$results[8]), cex.names = 0.8, xaxs = "i", add = TRUE)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando a linha abaixo veremos que o código de erro está apontando que o `xlab` e `ylab` que estão sendo populados com os dados contidos em `database$curso` e `database$results` não tem valor equivalente, sendo necessários serem preenchidos. Ou seja, o vetor contem mais elementos que valores:

```
barplot(database$results, main = "EvasionChart", xlab = rotulo[1], ylab = rotulo[2], names.arg = database$curso, ylim = c(0, database$results[8]), cex.names = 0.8, xaxs = "i")
```

*O erro* claro é que o `database$curso` aponta 10 elementos no vetor e o `database$results` preenche o vetor com 8 valores, deixando 2 indefinidos, tudo pode ser resolvido acrescentando 2 valores no `database$results` como no exemplo abaixo:

Antes:

```
database$results <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Depois:

```
database$results <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```